# How do I post diagrams in a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, stackexchange

How do I post a free body diagram or any rough sketch in a question? Is there a code or something else?

Comment: Are you asking how to *make* a diagram? Or how to *upload* one?

Answer (score 2):

I draw my diagrams using [Google Draw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drawings), then I screengrab the picture and paste it into my favourite image editor (Paint Shop Pro), tidy it up and save it as a GIF. The GIF can then be inserted into your question.